# Python creating subdirectory with user input

Tags: python, subdirectory, os.path

I am trying to make a script that makes a directory (name input)
and makes a second directory in that just created input folder.

```
import os
import sys


user_input = raw_input("Enter name: ")
user_input1 = raw_input('Enter case: ')

path = user_input
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
path = user_input1
if not os.path.exists(user_input/user_input1):
    os.makedirs(path)
```

I get

```
if not os.path.exists(user_input/user_input1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried doing this:

```
if not os.path.exists('/user_input1/user_input'):
```

But that results in it making two separate directories not subdirectories

Comment: You did mean `os.path.join(user_input, user_input1)`. What you wrote is dividing (the string) `user_input` by `user_input1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a sub directory, you need to concatenate the separator in between the two inputs which can be done as :

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(user_input, user_input1)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(user_input, user_input1))
```

You need to keep in mind that while checking for the second input string which is a sub directory, you pass `os.path.join(user_input, user_input1)`, as passing only `user_input1` would not create a sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.exists()` is expecting a string. Use this instead:

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(user_input, user_input1):
    os.makedirs(path)
```

Also to make your code easier to read you shouldn't reuse the `path` variable like that. It make sit confusing to others reading your code. This is much clearer:

```
import os
import sys


path1 = raw_input("Enter name: ")
path2 = raw_input('Enter case: ')

if not os.path.exists(path1):
    os.makedirs(path1)
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(path1, path2):
    os.makedirs(path2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
import os
import sys

user_input = raw_input("Enter name: ")
user_input1 = raw_input('Enter case: ')

path1 = user_input
if not os.path.exists(path1):
    os.makedirs(path1)
path2 = user_input1
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(user_input, user_input1)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path1, path2))
```